# unexpected token fi in bashrc

Tags: linux, bash

I was editing some environmental variables when I encountered this error:

```
bash: /home/splacorn/.bashrc: line 115: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
bash: /home/splacorn/.bashrc: line 115: `  fi'
```

This if-statement-block is causing the issue but I don't see any unexpected characters and it's breaking my bashrc. I've tried removing the space in front of the fi but it still doesn't work. How do I fix this? Thanks.

```
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
  fi
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Comment: Take a closer look at that first `if` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell, unlike other programming languages you may be familiar with, does not allow empty blocks.  In your code,

```
if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
  . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
   #HERE
fi
```

you must put at least one command where I have marked `#HERE`.

In this case, it appears to me that the problem is that the `fi` and the following line have gotten swapped, i.e. the code is meant to read

```
if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
  . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
  . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

In the general case, if you need an empty block for some reason, the conventional thing to put in there is a single `:`, which is the shortest and most efficient way to write a no-op command in shell.  For instance

```
if grep -q particular_setting /etc/daemon.conf; then
  :
else
  sed -i -e '$a\
particular_setting=true
' /etc/daemon.conf
fi
```

(In a portable shell script you can't use `if ! ...` so you *have* to write do-unless-condition constructs this way.  That's obviously not a concern in a bash rc file.)

Comment: `if ! ...` is [absolutely defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02), at least as long as `...` is not a `(...)` subshell.

Comment: @chepner You've probably never had to deal with a system where `/bin/sh`'s behavior was deliberately frozen at "whatever it used to do in 1992" and there *might* be a POSIX-compliant shell environment hiding somewhere in `/usr` if you were lucky and the sysadmin had installed that optional add-on. *hollow, bitter laughter*

Comment: I don't consider "must work on my 25-year-old legacy system" to be part of a useful definition of "portable".

Comment: @chepner The thing is, if you know you have something better, then you also know you have the option of writing something other than a shell script, which is always the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an empty body in an `if` statement; you need at least the dummy command `:`:

```
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    :
  fi
  . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

The error is saying that the parser is seeing the token `fi`, which terminates the `if` statement, before it sees the command that it expects following the keyword `then`.